# Can time zone manipulation be done in PostgreSQL? Would PostgreSQL have access to the current user's time zone?

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timezone-offset

I have dates stored as a **DATE** value in PostgreSQL like this: `06-JUN-2022`.

I am needing to change it to a time stamp and have the time be the equivalent of 9 AM in New York for the user's time zone:

- For users in Utah (2 hours behind New York), the time would be set to 7 AM because when it is 7 AM in Utah, it is 9 AM in New York.
- For users in California (3 hours behind New York), the time would be set to 6 AM because when it is 6 AM in California, it is 9 AM in New York.

I was easily able to do this in JavaScript on the front-end using the **date-fns-tz** package—when my computer's time is manually set to Utah time, when given the date `06-JUN-2022`, the returned value is `Mon Jun 06 2022 07:00:00 GMT-0600`, which is exactly what I want. The code is as follows:

```
const { zonedTimeToUtc } = require("date-fns-tz");

export function fixTimeZone(date) {
  let currentTimeStamp = new Date((date += " 09:00::00"));
  let correctTimeStamp = zonedTimeToUtc(currentTimeStamp, "America/New_York");

  return correctTimeStamp;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve a similar result in PostgreSQL, so the dates are converted to a timestamp with the correctly-altered time before they are sent to the client? Does PostgreSQL even have access to the user's time zone, or must it be done on the front-end?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select 
   ('06-JUN-2022'::date + time '9:00') 
at time zone 'America/New_York' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver';
      timezone       
---------------------
 06/06/2022 07:00:00


select 
   ('06-JUN-2022'::date + time '9:00') 
at time zone 'America/New_York' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles';
      timezone       
---------------------
 06/06/2022 06:00:00
```

See [AT TIME ZONE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) for more information.

Comment: This seems like it might work. The only thing is, Utah and California were just two examples. Is there any way for SQL to do something similar but while using the current user's time zone, wherever they may be?

Comment: Postgres does not have access to the client 's time zone unless there is some external code that grabs it and makes it available in the front end code.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions. Thank you!